# Pass a Sequelize model as property in Node using Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I'm building a project with Node, Typescript and Sequelize. I want to define a GENERAL controller with the following functionality:

```
class Controller {
  Schema: <Sequelize-Model>;

  constructor(schema: <Sequelize-Model>) {
    this.Schema = schema
  }

  find(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    return this.Schema
      .findWithCount(req.query)
      .then(collection => res.status(200).json(collection))
      .catch(next);
  }
}
```

Problem is, I don't know what type to use in . I've tried with **any**, **Model** from Sequelize, **Model** from sequelize-typescript, and a few more options. Ideas?

Comment: Hey there, I'm having the same problem. How did you solve it?

Comment: I found this and it works perfectly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57141896/9834967

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this,

**Model:**

```
@Table({
 })

 export class model1 extends Model<model1> {
     @PrimaryKey
     @Column({
         allowNull: false,
         type: DataType.UUID,
     })
     public id: string;

 }
```

**Class**

```
 import { model1 } from '../../model/model1';
 export default class Repository {
     public find(req: any): Promise<any> {
         return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
             model1.findAndCount({
                 where: req.query
             }).then(
                 (results) => {
                     resolve(results);
                 },
                 err => {
                     reject(err);
                 }
             );
         });
     }
 }
```