# TypeScript & Sequelize: Pass in generic Model

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, typescript-generics

I have this code

```js
import { Model, DataTypes, Sequelize } from "sequelize";

class User extends Model {
    public id!: number;
    public firstName!: string;
    public readonly createdAt!: Date;
    public readonly updatedAt!: Date;
}

function async InitAndDefineModel(model: Model): void {
    const sequelize = new Sequelize({
        dialect: "sqlite",
        storage: ":memory:",
    });
    model.init{
        firstName: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
        },
    },
    {
        sequelize,
    });
    const tables = await sequelize.showAllSchemas({});
    console.log(tables);
}

InitAndDefineModel(User);
```

The console.log statement returns:

```
// [ { name: 'Users' } ]
```

So I know the code works, however, TypeScript complains that:

```
Property 'init' is a static member of type 'Model<any, any>'ts(2576)
```

on the `model.init(...)` call.

I think TS thinks I'm passing in a Model object directory. I guess I need to tell it it's a type of Model, or the object passed in was extended from it.
How do I tell TypeScript that the argument `model: Model` is valid? I tried to use `model: Model<T>` and `model: T any other variations, but to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should create a static type representation of your models like:

```js
type ModelStatic = typeof Model & {
  new(values?: object, options?: Sequelize.BuildOptions): Model;
}
```

And you could define the `InitAndDefineModel` function like this:

```js
function async InitAndDefineModel(model: ModelStatic): void
```

In such a case the `model` passed to above function should now allow to access static methods of `Sequelize.Model`

Comment: I had to tweak your type definition slightly to satisfy TS lint rules to: `type ModelStatic = typeof Model & (new(values?: object, options?: BuildOptions) => Model);`. Aside from that, it worked. Thank you.

Comment: `export abstract class EntityService<Entity> {
readonly entity;

async findById(id: number): Promise<Entity> {
  const model = await this.entity.findByPk(id)
  if (model) return model
  throw new NotFoundException()
 }
} `

Hi, can you help with the above?
How would I set types for the property `entity` in `EntityService` class so that I can get intellisense functionality in the findById function?