# How to pass Model sequelize as parameter?

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

i try to pass a model class as parameter, but typescript doesn't see methods, properties.

```js
import type { Model } from 'sequelize';

const isExistsValidator = (model: typeof Model, field: string) => {
  return async (value): boolean => {
    const result = await model.findOne({ where: { [field]: value } }); // No overload matches this call.
    // ...
  };
};
```

I have tried some variants:

```js
import type { Model, ModelStatic } from 'sequelize';

const isExistsValidator = <M extends Model>(model: ModelStatic<M>, field: string) { 
  // ...
  const result = await model.findOne({ where: { [field]: value } });// Property 'findOne' does not exist on type
}
```

```js
import type { Model } from 'sequelize';

const isExistsValidator = (model: Model, field: string) { 
  // ...
  const result = await model.findOne({ where: { [field]: value } });// Property 'findOne' is a static member of type 'Model<any, any>'
```

How it will be use (something like this):

```js
const isExistsName = isExistsValidator(UserModel, 'name');
// ...
if(await isExistsName('alex4answer')) {
  throw new Error('Name already in use');
}
```

What am i doing wrong?
i'm new in typescript

Comment: The error in the ModelStatic case is snipped. Could please write the whole error for all cases?

Comment: @ShivamSingla, Property 'findOne' does not exist on type 'ModelStatic<M>

Comment: Could please add more verbose errors for all cases?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57129544/typescript-sequelize-pass-in-generic-model) if it works for you

Comment: @Shivam Singla, vscode displays only the errors I described, without details.
i've tried that: 
```<M extends Model>(model: ModelCtor<M>, field: string) ```.
ModelCtor declared in sequelize:
```
export type ModelCtor<M extends Model> = typeof Model & { new(): M };
```

Comment: then i got error: ```const result = await model.findOne({ where: { [field]: value } });
                                                           ^^^^^
The expected type comes from property 'where' which is declared here on type 'NonNullFindOptions<M["_attributes"]>```